# How do I insert blank rows within a list based on another list's values?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I was hoping to get a solution in Google sheets or Apps Script that achieves the below. As you can see, Project List 1 has some values that are called "New Line". I would like my desired list to be Project List 2 with inserted blank cells if List 1 has "New Line".

| Projects 1 | Projects 2 | List I Want |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Cat1 | Cat11 | Cat11 |
| Dog1 | Dog11 | Dog11 |
| New Line | Cat22 |  |
| Cat2 | Dog22 | Cat22 |
| Dog2 | Cat33 | Dog22 |
| Cat3 | Dog33 | Cat33 |
| New Line | Cat44 |  |
| Cat4 | Dog44 | Dog33 |
| Dog4 | Cat55 | Cat44 |
| Cat5 | Dog55 | Dog44 |
| Dog5 |  | Cat55 |
|  |  | Dog55 |

Not sure what the best approach is, any ideas are welcome!

Comment: Search Documentation for insertRow.

Comment: The markdown for columns has not been successful. Suggest you edit your question to confirm how the columns should appear.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try:

```
=let(Σ,map(A2:A,scan(,A2:A,lambda(a,c,if(c="New Line",a,a+1))),lambda(a,z,if(a="",,if(a="New Line",z,)))),
       index(substitute(tocol({B2:B,if(xlookup(sequence(rows(B2:B)),Σ,Σ,),"",)},1),"",)))
```

[image]

Comment: This did the trick!! Thank you so much, it has saved me a lot of time :)